# Product of Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two graphs. The product of $G_1$ and $G_2$ is defined by
$$V(G_1 \times G_2) = V(G_1) \times V(G_2) \; \text{and} $$

$((a,b) , (c,d)) \in E(G_1 \times G_2) $  iff either $a = c$ and $(b,d) \in E(G_2)$ or $b=d$ and $(a,c) \in E(G_2)$.

Can we generalize this product upto $n$ graphs like this.

Comment: What about defining inductively $$G_1 \times \cdots \times G_n = (G_1 \times \cdots \times G_{n-1}) \times G_n$$?

Comment: @Struggler That doesn’t make sense.  If you take the cartesian product of $n$ vertex sets, then the elements will be $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ where each $a_i \in G_i$, not $a_i \in G_1$ for some vertices and $a_i \in G_2$ for others.

Comment: @Eric:  This is an typo error.  I mean to say that 
 
How can we define the the edge between two vertices $(a_1,a_2\cdots,a_n)$
and $(b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n)$, where $a_i , b_i \in G_i $

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer, if $G_1, G_2,\cdots,G_n$ are graphs,then we can define their product $G = G_1 \times G_2 \times \cdots \times G_n$
$$V(G) = V(G_1) \times \cdots \times V(G_n)$$

Two distinct vertices $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ and $(b_1, \cdots,b_n)$ are adjacent iff there exist unique $1 \leq i \leq n$ such that $a_i$ and $b_i$ are adjacent in $G_i$ and $a_j = b_j$ for all $j \neq i.$